# can i create user defined db in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

```
 q = "create table ? " + databasename + " (emp_id number (10), emp_name varchar (15));"
```

Comment: please read how to ask a GOOD question

Comment: Yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962028/create-table-in-by-sql-statement-using-executeupdate-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create table in by sql statement using executeUpdate in Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962028/create-table-in-by-sql-statement-using-executeupdate-in-mysql)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? The answers wont be the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### try this:

```
 q = "create table  " + databasename + " (emp_id number (10), emp_name varchar (15))"
```